# phonegap cordova json parse)

Tags: ios, json, cordova, parsing

I've been working on a project with cordova about blog bases. I listed the blog pages according to their categories. I can take data from Json but i cannot list the singleblogs. I call it with callback method but i can't see anything in the phone screen except dummy data. I'll be glad if you can help me. Thank you

(i edited this question; is new)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how to json parsing using  javascript for phonegap cordova

Comment: your code should work perfectly in phonegap.

Comment: I oculdnt see my iphone :( what am i wrong

Comment: I don't know what you mean, when you say you couldn't see your Iphone. I think you're having problems compiling your app, aren't you?

Comment: thanks for your answer. Its working but the appearance of the phone is very corrupt. How we can fix it ? I would be glad if you can assist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I see on the code, In Cordova there is a event fired when the device is ready, you must put this code inside a method and add listener, instead the document ready of JQuery:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady(){
   alert("I'm Working");
}
```

Secondly, you have to include a javascript file called cordova.js in your HTML file, depending the way you're building your app you can find that file.

This guide can help you out.

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/guide/getting-started/ios/

Comment: thanks for your answer. Its working but the appearance of the phone is very corrupt. How we can fix it ? I would be glad if you can assist

Comment: What do you mean with corrupt appearance?

Comment: not as a native app or a responsive website that looks bad looks like a website from the phone entered

Comment: Can you post an image?

Comment: looks like if it doesn't apply CSS rules

Comment: Yes , How can i fix it

Comment: i posted new question

Comment: @HulyaYavz What do you mean? I don't see another question recently posted by you